# Implementation of numpy in1d for 2D arrays?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2D numpy array S representing a state space, with 80000000 rows (as states) and 5 columns (as state variables).

I initialize K0 with S, and at each iteration, I apply a state transition function f(x) on all of the states in Ki, and delete states whose f(x) is not in Ki, resulting Ki+1. Until it converges i.e. Ki+1 = Ki.

Going like this would take ages:

```
K = S
to_delete = [0]
While to_delete:
    to_delete = []
    for i in xrange(len(K)):
        if not f(i) in K:
        to_delete.append(K(i))
    K = delete(K,to_delete,0)
```

So I wanted to make a vectorized implementation :

slice K in columns, apply f and, join them once again, thus obtaining f(K) somehow.

The question now is how to get an array of length len(K), say Sel, where each row Sel[i] determine whether f(K[i]) is in K. Exactly like the function in1d works.

Then it would be simple to make

```
K=K[Sel]]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is difficult to understand because it contains extraneous information and contains typos.  If I understand correctly, you simply want an efficient way to perform a set operation on the rows of a 2D array (in this case the intersection of the rows of `K` and `f(K)`).

You can do this with [numpy.in1d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) if you create [structured array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html) view.

Code:

if this is `K`:

```
In [50]: k
Out[50]:
array([[6, 6],
       [3, 7],
       [7, 5],
       [7, 3],
       [1, 3],
       [1, 5],
       [7, 6],
       [3, 8],
       [6, 1],
       [6, 0]])
```

and this is `f(K)` (for this example I subtract 1 from the first col and add 1 to the second):

```
In [51]: k2
Out[51]:
array([[5, 7],
       [2, 8],
       [6, 6],
       [6, 4],
       [0, 4],
       [0, 6],
       [6, 7],
       [2, 9],
       [5, 2],
       [5, 1]])
```

then you can find all rows in `K` also found in `f(K)` by doing something this:

```
In [55]: k[np.in1d(k.view(dtype='i,i').reshape(k.shape[0]),k2.view(dtype='i,i').
reshape(k2.shape[0]))]
Out[55]: array([[6, 6]])
```

`view` and `reshape` create flat structured views so that each row appears as a single element to `in1d`.  `in1d` creates a boolean index of `k` of matched items which is used to fancy index `k` and return the filtered array.

Comment: Great! but what is `dtype = 'i,i'` ? Could this method work if my rows are of any type and any number of columns? for instance rows like `[-0.5,0.5,1,-6,20]`.

Comment: @amine23  I've put a link to structured array documentation in my answer.  Yes, floats, strings, booleans are all allowed fields in a dtype struct.

Comment: I get `ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged` if I try your example. Haven't sorted out what's changed to break it (I have numpy 1.8.2, python 2.7.6).

Comment: Great solution. I had to use dtype='int,int' in my case. Otherwise the structured array was 2x the length of the original [N,2] array.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand your question entirely, but if the interpretation of Paul is correct, it can be solved efficiently and fully vectorized using the [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package as such in a single readable line:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
K = npi.intersection(K, f(K))
```

Also, this works for rows of any type or shape.

Answer (score 0):

Above answer is great.

But if one doesn't want to mingle with structured arrays and wants **a solution that doesn't care what is the type of your array, nor the dimensions of your array elements**, I came up with this :

```
k[np.in1d(list(map(np.ndarray.dumps, k)), list(map(np.ndarray.dumps, k2)))]
```

basically, `list(map(np.ndarray.dumps, k))`instead of `k.view(dtype='f8,f8').reshape(k.shape[0])`.

Take into account that this solution is ~50 times slower.

```
k = np.array([[6.5, 6.5],
       [3.5, 7.5],
       [7.5, 5.5],
       [7.5, 3.5],
       [1.5, 3.5],
       [1.5, 5.5],
       [7.5, 6.5],
       [3.5, 8.5],
       [6.5, 1.5],
       [6.5, 0.5]])
k = np.tile(k, (1000, 1))

k2 = np.c_[k[:, 0] - 1, k[:, 1] + 1]


In [132]: k.shape, k2.shape
Out[132]: ((10000, 2), (10000, 2))

In [133]: timeit k[np.in1d(k.view(dtype='f8,f8').reshape(k.shape[0]),k2.view(dtype='f8,f8').reshape(k2.shape[0]))]
10 loops, best of 3: 22.2 ms per loop

In [134]: timeit k[np.in1d(list(map(np.ndarray.dumps, k)), list(map(np.ndarray.dumps, k2)))]
1 loop, best of 3: 892 ms per loop
```

It can be marginal for small inputs, but for the op's, it will take 1h 20min instead of 2 min.