# How do I use numpy to find the unions between 2D and 3D arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array of integer tuples of length 3 (x) and a numpy array of integer tuples of length 2 (y).

```
x = numpy.array([[3, 4, 5], [5, 12, 13], [6, 8, 10], [7, 24, 25]]) #first 4 elem
y = numpy.array([[3, 4], [4, 5], [3, 5], [5, 12]]) # first 4 elem
```

I am trying to compare elements within array y: [a, b] **and** [b, c] **and** [a, c] that are subsets of a single element [a, b, c] within array x. I call this function union. My loop heavy method to find the union is shown below. This is not too good for my arrays that contain 200K minimum elements.

```
def union(x, y):
for intx in range (len(x)):
    cond1 = cond2 = cond3 = 0
    for inty in range (len(y)):
        if (y[inty][0] == x[intx][0] and y[inty][1] == x[intx][1]): #[a, b] & [a, b, c]
            print ("condition 1 passed")
            cond1 = 1
        if (y[inty][0] == x[intx][1] and y[inty][1] == x[intx][2]): #[b, c] & [a, b, c]
            print ("condition 2 passed")
            cond2 = 1
        if (y[inty][0] == x[intx][0] and y[inty][1] == x[intx][2]): #[a, c] & [a, b, c]
            print ("condition 3 passed")
            cond3 = 1
        if (cond1 & cond2 & cond3):
            print("union found with ", x[intx])
            cond1 = cond2 = cond3 = 0
return

>>> union(x,y)
condition 1 passed
condition 2 passed
condition 3 passed
union found with  [3 4 5]
condition 1 passed
```

UPDATE #1: Example 1: This set of x and y have no union:

```
x = numpy.array([[21, 220, 221]])
y = numpy.array([[21, 220], [20, 21], [220,3021], [1220,3621], [60,221]])
```

UPDATE #2: Example 2: This set of x and y have no union:

```
x = numpy.array([[43, 924, 925]])
y = numpy.array([[43, 924], [924, 1643], [924,4307], [72, 925]])
```

Example 3: Here is a set of x and y that have a union of [4, 8, 16].

```
x = numpy.array([[4, 8, 16], [8, 4, 16]])
y = numpy.array([[4, 8], [8, 16], [4, 16]])
```

Example 4: Here is a set of x and y that have a union of [12, 14, 15].

```
x = numpy.array([[12, 13, 15], [12, 14, 15]])
y = numpy.array([[12, 14], [12, 13], [12, 15], [14, 15]])
```

Summary: In general terms, array x and y will have a union of [a, b, c] if

```
x = numpy.array([[a, b, c], ...])
y = numpy.array([[a, b], [b, c], [a, c],...])
```

or random ordering in y

```
y = numpy.array([[...[b, c], [a, c], ... [a, b]])
```

So my question: Is there a numpy way to do an array-wise operation? 
For example, numpy.logical_and suggests that x1 and x2 must be the same shape.
It's not straightforward to me to replace my if statements with isdisjoint, which is a faster method. https://stackoverflow.com/a/24478521/8275288

Comment: You could include a `break` after the `cond1 = cond2 = cond3 = 0` line. But I'm not sure I really grasp what you're looking for. Just a question for my understanding: you need three pairs of `y` to find a union (if all elements in `x` are not equal)? Because one must match the first and second, one must match the second and third and one must match the first and third?

Comment: yes, that's correct.

Comment: @Stoddard can elements in y serve as union pieces for more than one element in x ?

Comment: @Rayhane yes, in theory. But the solution is where a single element in x has three simultaneous intersections in y fragments.

Comment: `x` is not 3d.  It may represent coordinates of points in 3d space.

Comment: why call `union(y, x)` with `def union(x, y)` ??? and please show at least 2 matches and a fail in your example data

Comment: So are you merely interested in a binary test? Or do you want to find the indices of the matching 2 and 3 tuples?

Comment: @Eelco - >99.999% of cases won't match. If one does, I would like the indices.

Comment: Would you like the 3 matching indices of the 2-tuples in y as well?

Comment: @Eelco - I misunderstood your question. I am only interested in the values of [a,b,c] and not the indices or its position in either array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package (disclaimer: I am its author) can be used to create a fairly straightforward vectorized version of your original code, which should be much more efficient:

```
from functools import reduce
import numpy_indexed as npi

def contains_union(x, y):
    """Returns an ndarray with a bool for each element in x, 
    indicating if it can be constructed as a union of elements in y"""
    idx = [[0, 1], [1, 2], [0, 2]]
    y = npi.as_index(y)   # not required, but a performance optimization
    return reduce(np.logical_and, (npi.in_(x[:, i], y) for i in idx))
```

Comment: should idx = [[0 1], [1, 2], [0, 2]]? Since I have all x and y sorted I can also optimize by stopping the search once y[0] > x[0].

Comment: Instead of `functools.reduce` you could simply use `np.logical_and.reduce(...)` or am I wrong?

Comment: Didnt think of that, but yeah that should give the same result; personally i slightly prefer the functools solution though, since it avoids unncessary intermediates.

Comment: I just tested it but it gives me `array([False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)` for `x = np.array([[3, 4, 5], [5, 12, 13], [6, 8, 10], [7, 24, 25]]); y = np.array([[3, 4], [4, 5], [3, 5], [5, 12]])` which seems wrong.

Comment: Good catch; npi.contains should have been npi.in_

Comment: x (96373 elements) and y (6754855 elements) returned results in 5.001435556994693 seconds wall-clock time (MacBook Pro)!

Comment: Glad to help; Out of curiousity, how does that timing compare to the non-vectorized version?

Comment: Is there a way to make this work on x and y arrays of dtype=object, one where int values are > int64, eg 10000000000000000000012345 (25 digits)?

Comment: If such arrays of objects can be np.argsort-ed (not sure, give it a try), then first casting them to npi.LexIndex before feeding them to any other npi functions should do the trick, yes.

Answer (score 3):

If you're just interested in the `x` "rows" that match your conditions you could use:

```
import numpy as np

def union(x, y):
    # Create a boolean mask for the columns of "x"
    res = np.ones(x.shape[0], dtype=bool)
    # Mask containing the "x" rows that have one "partial match"
    res_tmp = np.zeros(x.shape[0], dtype=bool)
    # Walk through the axis-combinations
    # you could also use Divakars "(x[:,:2], x[:,::2], x[:,1:])" here.
    for cols in (x[:, [0, 1]], x[:, [1, 2]], x[:, [0, 2]]):
        # Check each row of y if it has a partial match
        for y_row in y:
            res_tmp |= (y_row == cols).all(axis=1)
        # Update the overall mask and then reset the partial match mask
        res &= res_tmp
        res_tmp[:] = 0
    return res

x = np.array([[3, 4, 5], [5, 12, 13], [6, 8, 10], [7, 24, 25]])
y = np.array([[3, 4], [4, 5], [3, 5], [5, 12]])
mask = union(x, y)
print(mask)     # array([ True, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
print(x[mask])  # array([[3, 4, 5]])
```

Or for a different `y`:

```
y = np.array([[3, 4], [4, 5], [3, 5], [5, 12], [12, 13], [5, 13]])
mask = union(x, y)
print(x[mask])
# array([[ 3,  4,  5],
#        [ 5, 12, 13]])
```

It still has to loop twice but the inner operation `y_row == x[:, ax]` is vectorized. That should bring at least some (probably huge) speed improvement.

One could also vectorize the `for y_row in y` loop (using broadcasting), but if your `x` array and `y` are really big this wouldn't improve the performance much but it would use `len(x) * len(y)` memory (in some cases this could require more memory than you actually have - leading to an Exception or really poor performance because you fallback to swap memory).

Comment: The `res` and `x[res]` only produce an output when you're in an interactive prompt. In modules you have to use `print(res)` or `print(x[res])`. You could also wrap it as a function and return `res` or `x[res]` :)

Comment: That's the thing here, it would force copy there with `x[:, ax]`. Still a good thought!

Comment: @Stoddard Could you clarify which example gives an incorrect union? I tried all 4 and they produce the correct unions.

Comment: res_tmp[:] = 0 did the trick to reset the logic. x of 4950 and y of 2000 takes 0.11 sec.

Answer (score 0):

if your x values have a max less than sqrt of the max integer representation (use int 64?), then a numerical trick may work

I used int(1e6) just as a readable example

```
import numpy

#rolled up all of the examples
x = numpy.array([[3, 4, 5], [5, 12, 13], [6, 8, 10], [7, 24, 25],
                [21, 220, 221],
                [43, 924, 925],
                [4, 8, 16], [8, 4, 16],
                [12, 13, 15], [12, 14, 15]]) #all examples

#and a numpy array of integer tuples of length 2:

y = numpy.array([[3, 4], [4, 5], [3, 5], [5, 12],
                [21, 220], [20, 21], [220,3021], [1220,3621], [60,221],
                [43, 924], [924, 1643], [924,4307], [72, 925],
                [4, 8], [8, 16], [4, 16],
                [12, 14], [12, 13], [12, 15], [14, 15]]) #all examples

#then make a couple of transform arrays

zx=numpy.array([[int(1e6), 1, 0],
                [0, int(1e6), 1],
                [int(1e6), 0, 1],
                ])
zy = numpy.array([[int(1e6)], [1]])


# and the magic is: np.intersect1d(zx @ x[ix], y @ zy)

# just to see part of what is being fed to intersect1d
print(zx @ x[0])
 [3000004 4000005 3000005]  

print(y[:4] @ zy)
[[3000004]
 [4000005]
 [3000005]
 [5000012]]


# if len of the intersection == 3 then you have your match

y_zy = y @ zy # only calc once
for ix in range(len(x)):
    matches = len(np.intersect1d(zx @ x[ix], y_zy))
    print(ix, matches, x[ix] if matches == 3 else '')
0 3 [3 4 5]
1 2 
2 0 
3 0 
4 1 
5 1 
6 3 [ 4  8 16]
7 2 
8 2 
9 3 [12 14 15]
```

I don't know `intersect1d` speed, but according to the doc it could be improved if the `unique=True` flag could be set,  depends on your data

Comment: Nice approach, but why the grandiose 1e6? when a mask with zx = numpy.array([[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0]]) and zy = numpy.array([[1], [0]]) gives the same magic numbers for (zx @ x[0]) and (y[:4] @ zy

Comment: I am encoding the each of the [a,b], [b,c], [a,c] pairs as single ints, perhaps array mult is slower than masking but I expect comparison of 2 ints is faster than parsing 2 2 element arrays for equality