# Comparing 2 arrays for equal elements and deleting the entries from both arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose i have 2 numpy arrays which have elements like these:

```
arr1 = [[1, 2], [3, 5], [3, 4]]
arr2 = [[2, 3], [3, 4], [6, 6]]
```

**I want the resultant array to have `arr2` appended or horizontally stacked to 
 `arr1` containing the elements which are NOT present in both the arrays:**

```
arr3 = [[1, 2], [3, 5], [2, 3], [6, 6]]
```

As you can see, `[3, 4]` is not there in the expected resultant array. What is the best numpy and pythonic implementation for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about:

```
[l for l in arr1+arr2 if (arr1+arr2).count(l)==1]
```

output:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 5], [2, 3], [6, 6]]
```

or, if you want it a bit more efficient:

```
c=arr1+arr2
[l for l in c if c.count(l)==1]
```

Comment: @ADR I suggested also a bit more efficient code due to your comment :)

Comment: Yes yes for sure mate! Upvoted too :D I was checking the time it took for execution. It's fast! The average time it took was `0.0009s`

Comment: In fact, this solution is slow on large lists. But good and clean. If you have a short list all is OK.

Comment: Yes, this is a good clean "easy on the eye" method for small lists. @ADR the method which you suggested has the least execution time! This is awkward, i'm embarrassed! But i did ask for the best numpythonic approach so i have to accept the answer accordingly.

Comment: Well, a major plus point is the elegance of your code that is true. For big arrays though, ADR's method has less execution time. I wish i could accept both your answers! But since yours is easy to read, i'll accept yours.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a bit late to the party but here is an approach that leverages `numpy` speed at only moderate algorithmic cost: O(n log n). It turns out that for many sizes of the input arrays runtime is dominated by the cost of type conversions. See benchmarks below:

```
from timeit import timeit
import numpy as np

def make_inputs(N, ncol):
    global arr1, arr2, list1, list2, lot1, lot2
    # create making sure there are no duplicates *within* arr1 or arr2
    all_ = np.array(list(set(map(tuple, np.random.randint(0, 2 * N, (N + N//2, ncol))))))
    # create input of various data types
    arr1 = all_[np.random.choice(len(all_), N, False)]
    arr2 = all_[np.random.choice(len(all_), N, False)]
    list1 = arr1.tolist()
    list2 = arr2.tolist()
    lot1 = list(map(tuple, list1))
    lot2 = list(map(tuple, list2))

def np_unique_preserve_order(a, b):
    c = np.r_[a, b]
    cr = c.view(np.dtype("|S" + str(c.shape[-1] * c.dtype.itemsize)))
    uniq, inv, count = np.unique(cr.ravel(), return_inverse=True,
                                 return_counts=True)
    return c[(count==1)[inv], :]

def np_unique(a, b):
    c = np.r_[a, b]
    cr = c.view(np.dtype("|S" + str(c.shape[-1] * c.dtype.itemsize)))
    uniq, count = np.unique(cr.ravel(), return_counts=True)
    return uniq[count==1, None].view(c.dtype)

def np_sort(a, b):
    c = np.r_[a, b]
    cr = np.sort(c.view(np.dtype("|S" + str(c.shape[-1] * c.dtype.itemsize))).ravel())
    m = np.empty(cr.shape, bool)
    m[0] = True
    m[1:] = cr[:-1] != cr[1:]
    m[:-1] &= m[1:]
    return cr[m, None].view(c.dtype)

# check
make_inputs(1000, 2)
assert set(map(tuple, lot1)).symmetric_difference(set(map(tuple, lot2))) == set(map(tuple, np_sort(arr1, arr2)))
assert set(map(tuple, lot1)).symmetric_difference(set(map(tuple, lot2))) == set(map(tuple, np_unique(arr1, arr2)))
assert set(map(tuple, lot1)).symmetric_difference(set(map(tuple, lot2))) == set(map(tuple, np_unique_preserve_order(arr1, arr2)))


for N, ncol in ((10, 2), (10000, 2), (100000, 20)):
    make_inputs(N, ncol)
    results = []
    for inputs in 'lot', 'list', 'arr':
        res = []
        if inputs == 'lot':
            res.append('{:11.5f} ms'.format(timeit(f'list(set({inputs}1).symmetric_difference(set({inputs}2)))',
                 f'from __main__ import {inputs}1, {inputs}2', number=10) * 100))
        else:
            res.append('{:11.5f} ms'.format(timeit(f'list(set(map(tuple, {inputs}1)).symmetric_difference(set(map(tuple, {inputs}2))))',
                 f'from __main__ import {inputs}1, {inputs}2', number=10) * 100))

        res.append('{:11.5f} ms'.format(timeit(f'np_sort({inputs}1, {inputs}2)', f'from __main__ import {inputs}1, {inputs}2, np_sort',
                 number=10) * 100))
        res.append('{:11.5f} ms'.format(timeit(f'np_unique({inputs}1, {inputs}2)', f'from __main__ import {inputs}1, {inputs}2, np_unique',
                 number=10) * 100))
        res.append('{:11.5f} ms'.format(timeit(f'np_unique_preserve_order({inputs}1, {inputs}2)', f'from __main__ import {inputs}1, {inputs}2, np_unique_preserve_order',
                 number=10) * 100))
        results.append(res)
    results = zip(*results)
    appmin = lambda l: l + (min(l),)
    print(f'\nno rows {N}, no colums {ncol}')
    print('input type                           lot           list          array           best')
    print(f'symm_diff                ', *appmin(next(results)))
    print(f'np_sort                  ', *appmin(next(results)))
    print(f'np_unique                ', *appmin(next(results)))
    print(f'np_unique_preserve_order ', *appmin(next(results)))
```

Output:

```
no rows 10, no colums 2
input type                           lot           list          array           best
symm_diff                     0.00232 ms     0.00453 ms     0.02034 ms     0.00232 ms
np_sort                       0.03890 ms     0.03269 ms     0.03060 ms     0.03060 ms
np_unique                     0.04209 ms     0.04118 ms     0.04136 ms     0.04118 ms
np_unique_preserve_order      0.05289 ms     0.05253 ms     0.05253 ms     0.05253 ms

no rows 10000, no colums 2
input type                           lot           list          array           best
symm_diff                     3.71800 ms     8.30081 ms    21.92841 ms     3.71800 ms
np_sort                       7.98128 ms     8.09973 ms     2.80091 ms     2.80091 ms
np_unique                     8.49229 ms     8.25701 ms     3.00654 ms     3.00654 ms
np_unique_preserve_order     10.12377 ms     8.67133 ms     3.36172 ms     3.36172 ms

no rows 100000, no colums 20
input type                           lot           list          array           best
symm_diff                    97.83141 ms   211.20736 ms   590.15145 ms    97.83141 ms
np_sort                     317.73268 ms   316.50081 ms    89.97820 ms    89.97820 ms
np_unique                   324.68922 ms   326.89891 ms    98.06377 ms    98.06377 ms
np_unique_preserve_order    339.18597 ms   339.00286 ms   120.94041 ms   120.94041 ms
```

For very small arrays `symm_diff` is fastest, but for larger ones `np_sort` has a small edge when all methods are allowed to use the data type they are most comfortable with.

Comment: This is a really comprehensive solution! Thanks for this! You have my upvote.

Answer (score 2):

```
arr_3 = list(set(arr_1).symmetric_difference(set(arr_2)))
```

or:

```
arr_3 = list(set(map(tuple, arr_1))
    .symmetric_difference(set(map(tuple, arr_2))))
```

A little research:

```
from random import randint
from timeit import timeit

import itertools

arr1 = [[randint(0, 5), randint(0, 5)] for _ in range(1000)]
arr2 = [[randint(0, 5), randint(0, 5)] for _ in range(1000)]


def symmetric_difference(a, b):
    now_exists = set()
    results = []
    for e in itertools.chain(a, b):
        rerp_of_e = repr(e)
        if rerp_of_e not in now_exists:
            now_exists.add(rerp_of_e)
            results.append(e)

    return results


def method2(a, b):
    c = a + b
    return [l for l in c if c.count(l) == 1]


print(timeit('[l for l in arr1 + arr2 if (arr1 + arr2).count(l) == 1]', 'from __main__ import arr1, arr2',
             number=10) / 10)

print(timeit('method2(arr1, arr2)', 'from __main__ import arr1, arr2, method2',
             number=10) / 10)

print(timeit('list(set(map(tuple, arr1)).symmetric_difference(set(map(tuple, arr2))))',
             'from __main__ import arr1, arr2', number=10) / 10)

print(timeit('symmetric_difference(arr1, arr2)', 'from __main__ import arr1, arr2, symmetric_difference',
             number=10) / 10)
```

Output:

```
0.16653713929933542
0.14676828165012284
0.00030277483018301685
0.0008909022958581315
```

Comment: The arrays are numpy arrays, lists wont work for me. Plus numpy arrays cannot be hashed.

Comment: It can be converted to `tuple`. But yes, should be a better way to do this.

Comment: Whoa! This is the fastest method! I tried for large 2D arrays. Symmetric method is really good for arrays which have a large size. The second method which you proposed has the least execution time!  `2.14437940844, 0.0020706277306, 0.0064447811589` are the execution times for array size = 10000. There is a huge difference in the first method and the 2nd method. Could you please explain what it's doing?

Comment: The method applied in 3rd print statement has the least execution time, i was asking for the explanation of that. The one with `map`.

Comment: In the first case, the complexity of the algorithm is equal to O(n^2). That's because we use the list.count() method with complexity equal O(n) and we perform this operation n times. In my solution, we use access via hash (through the set()) which complexity equal  O(1). Then overall complexity of the algorithm equal O(n).
Sorry for my English)

Comment: Sorry so long. I needed time to translate.

Comment: Do you understand me?)

Comment: @hulkinBrain  - this method can be better if you give 0 weight to code readability and/or elegance. If, sometime, someone else should work with this code, or, if you are going to get back to it in the future and try to understand what you did - I would warmly suggest you to take my solution (and you really don't have to accept it if you don't want to...)

Answer (score 2):

If only items in same index can be similar you can use a simply numpythonic approach like following:

```
In [10]: mask = ~(arr1 == arr2).all(1)

In [11]: np.vstack((arr1[mask], arr2[mask]))
Out[11]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 5],
       [2, 3],
       [6, 6]])
```

Otherwise you can find the intersections based on [Jaime's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23814517/get-indices-of-intersecting-rows-of-numpy-2d-array) then exclude them from combined array.

Or use following approach:

```
In [17]: arr1_view = arr1.view([('', arr1.dtype)] * arr1.shape[1])

In [18]: arr2_view = arr2.view([('', arr2.dtype)] * arr2.shape[1])

In [19]: diff_arr1 = np.setdiff1d(arr1_view, arr2_view).view(arr1.dtype).reshape(-1, arr1.shape[1])

In [20]: diff_arr2 = np.setdiff1d(arr2_view, arr1_view).view(arr2.dtype).reshape(-1, arr2.shape[1])

In [21]: np.vstack((diff_arr1, diff_arr2))
Out[21]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 5],
       [2, 3],
       [6, 6]])
```

If you are dealing with python arrays and specially short arrays you can just use a list comprehension like following:

```
In [204]: [i for i in arr1 + arr2 if not (i in arr1 and i in arr2)]
Out[204]: [[1, 2], [3, 5], [2, 3], [6, 6]]
```

Note that its faster than converting the lists to tuple and using set for short arrays bit for larger arrays the set based approach takes the cake, which in that case it's still better to use Numpy:

```
In [209]: %timeit set(map(tuple, arr1)).symmetric_difference(map(tuple, arr2))
100000 loops, best of 3: 1.51 µs per loop

In [210]: %timeit [i for i in arr1 + arr2 if not (i in arr1 and i in arr2)]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.28 µs per loop
```

Comment: No, they can be present at any location. Thanks for pointing out the ambiguity in the question! I'll edit it now.

Comment: Yes Jaime's answer has a similar approach which i was trying to implement on my own using `numpy.intersect1d`. Didn't know a similar question existed! Thanks

Comment: @hulkinBrain Using that answer you need to do a lot of excluding since you will end up with indices. Checkout the update for a general vectorized approach.

Comment: I just pointed out that there could be a possible solution using intersection of the 2 arrays in which the indices of the intersection elements would be stored in an array and then would be used to remove the elements in the resultant array accordingly. I'll check your updated answer and report back

Comment: Yup, this works well too! Upvoted your answer :D Your method and beniev's method have similar average execution times even for large arrays (i tested both the methods). Nice pure numpy method though!

Comment: @hulkinBrain The previous method wasn't correct. Checkout the update for the correct method using views and `setdiff1d`.

Comment: Your method takes a little more time as compared to ADR's method. Good to know that there are more than one ways to solve my question! Thanks :D

Comment: @hulkinBrain That's because your arrays are too small. Try to benchmark with large arrays to see how much Numpy is faster. It's not comparable at all in that case. But if you are dealing with short arrays like this it's better to just ye python.

Comment: @hulkinBrain After all, checkout the update for a pythonic approach.

Comment: Yup you are right. I benchmarked with arrays with size 100000, there is great deal of difference but still the `symmetric_difference` method is the fastest. Thanks for this! I'm working with small arrays though so the difference is marginal for me.

Comment: I do not understand why you have the same result for this: `set(map(tuple, arr1)).symmetric_difference(map(tuple, arr2))` and this: `[i for i in arr1 + arr2 if not (i in arr1 and i in arr2)]`

I get: 0.00036 and 0.005

Comment: @ADR It's not the same the list comprehension is faster for a short list like this. But I don't know why you've got such different result.