# comparing two numpy arrays and adding same rows

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I have two large data files, one with two columns and one with three columns. I want to select all the rows from the second file that are contained in the fist array. My idea was to compare the numpy arrays.

Let's say I have:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5],  [1, 4, 6]])

b = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
```

and the result should look like this:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5]]
```

Any advice on that?

EDIT: 
So in the end this works. Not very handy but it works.

```
for ii in range(a.shape[0]):
    u, v, w = a[ii,:]
    for jj in range(b.shape[0]):
        if (u == b[jj, 0] and v == b[jj, 1]):
            print [u, v, w]
```

Answer (score 2):

The [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package (disclaimer: I am its author) contains functionality to solve such problems efficiently, without using any python loops:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
a[npi.contains(b, a[:, :2])]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to not use another library but want to do this in `numpy` only, you can do something similar to what is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16240957/6614295) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16216866/6614295), namely to use `np.in1d` (see [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html)) which does provide you with a mask indicating if an element in one 1D array exists in another 1D array. As the name indicates, this function only works for 1D arrays. But you can use a structured array view (using [`np.view`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html)) to cheat `numpy` into thinking you have 1D arrays. One caveat is though, that you need a deep copy of the first array `a` since `np.view` doesn't mix with slices, well. But if that is not too big of an issue for you, something along the lines of:

```
a_cp = a[:, :2].copy()
a[np.in1d(a_cp.view((np.void, a_cp.dtype.itemsize*a_cp.shape[1])).ravel(),
          b.view((np.void, b.dtype.itemsize*b.shape[1])).ravel())]
```

might work for you.

This directly uses the masked array to return the correct values from your array `a`.

Answer (score -1):

Check this, @Ernie. It may help you to get to the solution. ;D

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html

Comment: Link-only answers are disfavoured, and I'm not actually sure how in1d would help.

Comment: yeah, this doesnt really help since the function is only defined for a 1d array..